# Convert a (<=4) x 2 SQL result set to 1 x 8 result set

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've spent much too long trying to figure out how TSQL pivoting works, so I'm posting this hoping someone that understands pivots can help me.

So here's a representative source result set:
*Notice that there are only 3 rows, but that's still <=4.*

```
| Code  | Date       |
|-------|------------|
| 12345 | 2018-01-01 |
| 67890 | NULL       |
| 13579 | 2018-01-02 |
```

This is target result set I want from the source result set:

```
| Code_1 | Date_1     | Code_2 | Date_2 | Code_3 | Date_3     | Code_4 | Date_4 |
|--------|------------|--------|--------|--------|------------|--------|--------|
| 12345  | 2018-01-01 | 67890  | NULL   | 13579  | 2018-01-02 | NULL   | NULL   |
```

Comment: please include DDL and PIVOT query

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, what is meant by including the DDL? I haven't made any progress, so I have no PIVOT query.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti, the source result set will always contain <=4 rows.

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted, but could people please comment why before they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that does literally what you're asking by joining 2 pivot queries together:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (code INT, dt DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (12345, '1/1/2018')
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (67890, null)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (13579, '1/1/2018')

SELECT SQ1.Code_1, SQ2.Code_1, SQ1.Code_2, SQ2.Code_2, SQ1.Code_3, SQ2.Code_3, SQ1.Code_4, SQ2.Code_4
FROM
(
    SELECT [Code_1], [Code_2], [Code_3], [Code_4]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'Code_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS RowID, code FROM @tbl
    ) source
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(code)
        FOR RowID IN ([Code_1], [Code_2], [Code_3], [Code_4])
    )sq
)SQ1
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT [Code_1], [Code_2], [Code_3], [Code_4]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'Code_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS RowID, dt FROM @tbl
    ) source
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(dt)
        FOR RowID IN ([Code_1], [Code_2], [Code_3], [Code_4])
    )sq
)SQ2
```

Outputs:

```
Code_1  Code_1      Code_2  Code_2  Code_3  Code_3      Code_4  Code_4
12345   2018-01-01  67890   NULL    13579   2018-01-01  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Although I like both answers, this one uses a PIVOT as originally required by the question, so it wins. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want a max of 4 groups (8 columns).

You may also notice that in the Order By I use (Select null).  Without a proper sequence key, there is no gtd of order.

**Example**

```
Select Code_1 = max(case when Col=1 then Code end)
      ,Date_1 = max(case when Col=1 then Date end)
      ,Code_2 = max(case when Col=2 then Code end)
      ,Date_2 = max(case when Col=2 then Date end)     
      ,Code_3 = max(case when Col=3 then Code end)
      ,Date_3 = max(case when Col=3 then Date end)     
      ,Code_4 = max(case when Col=4 then Code end)
      ,Date_4 = max(case when Col=4 then Date end)     
 From (
        Select *
              ,Col = Row_Number() over (Order by (Select null))  
         From  @YourTable
      ) A
```

**Returns**

```
Code_1   Date_1     Code_2  Date_2  Code_3  Date_3      Code_4  Date_4
12345   2018-01-01  67890   NULL    13579   2018-01-01  NULL    NULL
```